# How to change the URL when paging using UI Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular JS project using Angular UI-Router which is going great but I am trying to implement the UI Bootstrap pagination directive and can't work out the correct strategy.

I have a table of data shown 1 page at a time and I have the pagination directive in place showing the correct number of page links. When you click a link it gets the new page number and makes a Restangular call to the api to get the new records and binds them to the table.

That's all working well, but obviously when you page through the data the URL doesn't change so the user can't use the browser back/forward buttons to navigate their history. Ideally I would like to use the following URLs:

```
/contacts
/contacts/page-2
/contacts/page-3
```

I would also like to include sorting in the URL but that's another question.

I could achieve this but by manually transitioning to a new state when one of the pagination buttons is clicked, but that would reload the controller and all of it's contents, making additional ajax calls to the server and making ugly flashes of un-styled content as it recreated the pagination control etc.

Ideally I would be able to change the URL and add a history state but without triggering an actual state change and reloading/running the controller for that view. I'm not sure if this is even possible, let alone how to do it.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easily achievable with $stateParams

For example

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts',{
 url: '/contacts',
 templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
}).state('contacts.paginated', {
    url: "/contacts/page-:pageNum",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        // If we got here from a url of /contacts/page-2
        expect($stateParams).toBe({pageNum: 2});
    }
})
```

I would choose a different pagination scheme however
Either /contacts/page/1 or /contacts?page=1
both are easily achievable with ui-router

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, but maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. Your solution shows how to set up the router to handle URLs for paging, but my question was about how to do the paging inside the controller and update the URL without actually re-loading/re-running the controller logic.

Comment: In this case if youre reusing the same state, for example 'contacts.paginated' and just changing the state params, the template will be cached and you will just need to get your new data based on the $stateParams data. I dont see how thats would cause any flashing. And no, controller doesnt get reinitialized in this case

Comment: So if I use the same state (contacts.paginated) and alter the $stateParams will the URL change in the address bar and allow browser history to work?

Comment: you can need to use $state.go('contacts.paginated', {pageNum: 2}) in order to update the $stateParams associated with this state

Comment: I'm going to have to have a play with this but unless I'm wrong, using $state.go() will cause a controller reload.

Comment: define what you mean by controller reload. The page will not reload unless you explicitly set reload in one of the options: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: OK, I tried  $state.go('contacts.paginated', {pageNum: 2}) and it did update the URL and didn't reload the controller. In fact it continued executing further code after the $state.go(). Unfortunately, the browser back button updated the URL but didn't cause the controller code to execute again so nothing happens on the page :(

Comment: I mean that code in the controller is executed again. When I go from /3 to /4 and then click the back button the controller code is not executed so although the URL changes back to /3 the pagination directive stays on page 4 and my list of data doesn't reload as nothing is running. It's a tricky problem because when somebody uses the pagination control I want it to call a pageChanged() function and modify the URL but not execute the whole controller again. However, when they use the browser back and forward buttons I need it to actually reload the results. BTW thank you for your patience.

Comment: I would knock up a quick JSfiddle or Plunkr to demonstrate, but it's not a simple thing and you can't see the URL in the address bar in those sites anyway, so I'm sorry I can't make this easier.

Comment: Just to add - I think it is exactly the same problem that this guy is having... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749097/ui-router-and-purposeful-transition-to-the-same-state

Comment: I have solved this by only updating the results when the params change and using $scope.$watchCollection('$stateParams') to detect when that happens. This also works when using the browser back button. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem