# Pagination and UI Router in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-router

I have AngularJS project with UI Router and I use Pagination in this project. I use directive and filter to make it by below code.

Controller

```
newsapp.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Route

```
newsapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('news', {
        url: "/news",
        templateUrl: "templates/news.html",
        controller: "imageNewsCtrl"
    })  
        .state('newsThumbnail', {
        url: "/news/:nameCat",
        templateUrl: "templates/news-thumbnail.html",
        controller: "newsPageCtrl"
    })
        .state('newsDetail', {
        url: "/news/:nameCat/:idItem",
        templateUrl: "templates/news-detail.html",
        controller: "newsDetailPageCtrl"
    });
```

Html

```
    <div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 box-preview" id="cat-{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item in imageItems | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            <a ui-sref="newsThumbnail({ nameCat: item.linkCat })" ng-class="{'activeCat': $index == div_no && side == 2 || hovering == true }" ng-mouseenter="hovering=true" ng-mouseleave="hovering=false">
                <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}" err-SRC="../images/no-image.png" class="img-ratio-respec">
                <div class="caption" ng-class="{'activeCat': $index == div_no && side == 2 || hovering == true}">{{item.nameCat}}</div>
            </a>    
        </div>                                            
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 menu-control-bar">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="buttLeft" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1 || currentPage == 0" ng-class="{'focus': but_no == 1 && side == 3 }" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
             {{currentPage+1}} / {{numberOfPages()}}
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="buttRight" ng-disabled="currentPage >= imageItems.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1" ng-class="{'focus': but_no == 2 && side == 3 }" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want use back button to history of pagination. If I choose page 2 in state **news**, select item for view other page. When I click back button, I want to show previous page I choose. ([like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290741/how-to-change-the-url-when-paging-using-ui-router) but I din't understand. sorry)

How about idea for this or suggest me.

Thanks :)